# Delete All Between ( and )

Tags: php, preg-replace, parentheses

I want to replace everything between `(` and `)`. And it also works with this preg_replace().

```
$return =  preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/", "", $return);
```

If my `$return` is like `"Hello my name is Frank (nicer guy)"`

the string is `"Hello my name is Frank"`

But in case that between the Parentheses are also next Parentheses it does not work. For example:

**before:**

`"Hello my name is Frank (nicer (guy) thank you)"`

**after**

`"Hello my name is Frank thank you)"`

it stops after the first ")". Is it possible that it also deletes the Parentheses inside the Parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match everything beginning with the first `(` and then backtrack to the last occurrence of `)`:

```
\(.*\)
```

**Note:** The `*` must be greedy for this to work. So make sure the ungreedy [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `U` is not set (default).

---

If your strings can contain multiple occurrences of independent parenthesized substrings, i.e. `"Hello (my name is) Frank (nicer (guy) thank you)"`, then you need a [recursive pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

The example `\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)` there works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for you:

```
<?php
  $in = '"Hello my name is Frank (nicer guy)"';
  $out = preg_replace('/\s\(.*\)/','',$in);
  echo $out;
?>
```

Output will be: "Hello my name is Frank"